# My Stack Overflow question asking about the SO tag implementation was closed, should it be re-opened, or where should I ask it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions

I [asked the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257235/so-tags-style-grid-filter) on Stack Overflow. It was closed as off-topic by George Stocker.

> I have a grid similar to SO tags page and want to implement the same style of filtering as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags). Is there any plugin, doesn't matter commercial or not. And if you can point me the resource where I can learn more how those type of things are implemented that would be much appreciated.

Is this question appropriate for Stack Overflow? If not, where should I ask this question? At the end of the day SO is created to help people.

Comment: I'm editing your question so it stays open. If you ask a programming question on Meta, it would normally get closed because this isn't where you ask programming questions. I'm editing it to focus on the two questions you ask (somewhat implicitly): 1) Why was it closed, and 2) if SO isn't the place for it, where should it be asked?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I agree that's a better approach. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I closed your question for the following reasons:

1. It asks for an offsite resource, which is explicitly against the site's focus.

   > Is there any plugin, doesn't matter commercial or not. And if you can point me the resource where I can learn more how those type of things are implemented that would be much appreciated.

   At best, this would produce a list of implementations in various forms and languages.  Its usefulness would be limited since off site answers are only as useful as whether their links are still alive.
2. You're asking for code, but you haven't helped us out with what you've tried.  There's another close reason that talks about that: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal amount of the problem being solved. Show us what you've tried, what didn't work, and what the expected results were.

As your question is currently written, it's not ontopic for any Stack Exchange site. To improve it, take out the part where you're asking for an off-site resource or tool (commercial or not), try to implement it yourself, and come back with a question that's a little more focused. If your question begets answers that happen to be libraries, so be it; but those answers should give more than just links -- they should show you how to incorporate it into the existing code you have in your question (*hint, hint*).

Comment: Well you could have removed the part about external plugin and left only the part asking how to implement those type of things. As for what I have tried so far please check comments. I agree may be it is not a usual topic, but don't you think that was a little picky.

Comment: @Tamerlane I don't see any code in your comments -- also remember that you should be editing more information into the question itself -- not keeping it in the comments.  Comments are ephemeral and can be deleted at any time. If you want us to use it to help you, it needs to be in the text of the question (for everybody's sake).

Comment: @Tamerlane: Not George's (or anyone elses) responsibility. **You** should edit out the part about external plugin, and should have edited your question to provide the information about what you've tried in the question itself instead of in comments.

Comment: I guess I am just wasting my time here as well as yours...You can edit/delete or even vaporize that question...but I do believe that site was not created to be this

Comment: @Tamer You are correct - the site was not created to answer the type of question you asked. You are the one who wants the answer to the question, so the burden is on **you** to improve it so that it meets the standards of the site. Otherwise, it will stay closed, and that's the whole point of the closing system: to limit the questions on the site to those that meet its standards.